# How do I loop through an object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to map an object like this in a  but it doesn't work.

```
manager:  [{…}]
0:
  12:
  name: "Name1"
  surname: "Surname1"
  agenda: Array(2)
       0: {date: "2020-05-27", start_at: "09:00:00", end_at: "10:00:00"}
       1: {date: "2020-05-27", start_at: "10:00:00", end_at: "11:00:00"}
  length: 2
  __proto__: Array(0)
  __proto__: Object

  13: {name: "Name2", surname: "Surname2", agenda: Array(1)}
  __proto__: Object
  length: 1
  __proto__: Array(0)
```

How can I do??

Firstly I have an array (without agenda) and I have done in this way, but now it doesn't work.

```
<select title="Choose" onChange={(event) => this.handleChangeManager(event)}>
           <option value="" title="Choose" data-content="Cancel <span class='reset-label'></span>"></option>
            {managers && managers.length && managers.map((manager, key) => (
              <option key={key}  value= {manager.id}  name="manager_id" >{manager.name} {manager.surname}</option>
            ))}
            </select>
```

I would have the possibility to create a  using the name and surname, but also to enter inside the Agenda array (in this case I should do something like manager.agenda.date to visualize the date?)

Comment: Is your managers variable have the correct data?

Comment: It seems `manager` is an array, but not exactly sure what content does it have inside it. Can you share an image of what you get from `console.log( manager )`

Comment: @Md.MoshfiqurRahmanRony yes the data is correct

Comment: What do you mean by :"It doesnt work" ? Do you get any error (if yes please share it) or does it just render empty ?

Comment: No i don't have error only my select is empty

Comment: @palaѕн I have add the image

Comment: Ok, I got the issue here. but what you mean by the next part "_but also to enter inside the Agenda array_" ? How that will effect the render method?

Comment: Btw : i do not see any "id" atttribute of the manager...

Comment: it is the first number 12 or 13

Comment: @palaѕн about the second part I mean that In the code that i posted I control only the managers attributes, I would control also the agenda attributes for each manager

Comment: I have a solution for 1st part, but I am still not clear on the 2nd part.

Comment: @palaѕн What I mean is that I would to print in the select also the agenda attributes

Comment: ok, but agenda is an array so how can you print all manager data and all agenda data in single `<option/>`?

Comment: In two different select I would to print in a select the manager, when the manager is choosen in the other select print the agenda attributes about this manager

Comment: ok, I would suggest breaking your question into two. First would be to ask how to display manager data (_already done_). then after getting the answer, you yourself could work on implementing the on change function for manager select, because now you will get manager id.. so next question you can ask on how to create another select based on manager id and managers array. That would help you a lot in the learning process.

Comment: Ok thank you. So at the moment I would to know how to display manager data

Comment: @Jack23 I see 2 variables here `managers` and `manager` (inside map). Can you confirm the console.log screen you posted is for `managers` or `manager`

Comment: the variable is `managers`

Comment: Please try working on 2nd part for some time. If you are not able to make any progress at all then post a new question regarding it and also share the manager array image. Also, post the new question link here. I will try to take a look if I am free around that time.

Comment: @palaѕн https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61631855/react-map-an-array-inside-object 
unfortunately I tried but nothing comes to mind to visualize the result inside the render.

Comment: Sorry, I am late but glad that your 2nd part was also resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you want to access data stored in `manager` array as object and `.map()` method can not be used on the object. For this, you can use the [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) method, as you also need the object key which is actually the `manager.id`.

So, assuming `manager` here is the main array we would simply do:

```
{manager && manager.length && Object.entries(manager[0]).map(([k, v]) => (
   <option 
     key={k}  
     value={k}  
     name="manager_id" >
     {v.name} {v.surname}
   </option>
))}
```

**Note:** Please know that you will need to use `Object.entries(manager[0])` here as `manager[0]` is the actually object here.

Here is a simple demo to understand what `Object.entries()` method does:

```js
const obj = {
  12: {name: 'Name1'},
  13: {name: 'Name2'}
};

Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => {
  console.log(`${k} ${v.name}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your manager is an array of objects as follows:

```
manager:  [{…}]
0:
  12:
  name: "Name1"
  surname: "Surname1"
  agenda: Array(2)
       0: {date: "2020-05-27", start_at: "09:00:00", end_at: "10:00:00"}
       1: {date: "2020-05-27", start_at: "10:00:00", end_at: "11:00:00"}
  length: 2
  __proto__: Array(0)
  __proto__: Object

  13: {name: "Name2", surname: "Surname2", agenda: Array(1)}
  __proto__: Object
  length: 1
  __proto__: Array(0)
```

If you want to map the managers in it then you have to loop the manager array and then then map the managers at each key again.

This is because of the nesting you have in the data:

manager:  [{…}]

**0:**

**12:**

Or you can access the first element of manager array and map that in render:

```
...
manager=Object.values(manager[0]) //Do checking here if 0 is actually an object. Object doesn't have .map
...
render(
...
<select title="Choose" onChange={(event) => this.handleChangeManager(event)}>
       <option value="" title="Choose" data-content="Cancel <span class='reset-label'></span>"></option>
        {managers && managers.map((manager, key) => (
          <option key={key}  value= {manager.id}  name="manager_id" > 
 {manager.name} {manager.surname}</option>
        ))}
        </select>
```