# React: Map an array inside object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to show (in a select) the values of agenda that is an array inside an object.

So what I would to obtain is a process like this: the user select a manager --> the user select the agenda values about this manager (this process in two different select).

My problem is how to process the second choose in the render.

My object is like:

```
manager:  [{…}]
0:
  12:
  name: "Name1"
  surname: "Surname1"
  agenda: Array(2)
       0: {date: "2020-05-27", start_at: "09:00:00", end_at: "10:00:00"}
       1: {date: "2020-05-27", start_at: "10:00:00", end_at: "11:00:00"}
  length: 2
  __proto__: Array(0)
  __proto__: Object
```

My code is:

```
handleChangeManager = (e) => {
      const manager_id = e.target.value;
      console.log("manager_id: ", manager_id)
      this.setState({manager_id : manager_id})
     this.agenda(manager_id)
    }

// I have tried this to recover the agenda's information about the manager choosen. 
    agenda(manager_id)
    {
      let agendas = this.props.managers[0][manager_id].agenda
      let mappingAgenda = agendas && agendas.length && agendas.map((agenda) => (
       console.log(agenda.date)

      ))
    }

render() {
         let managers = this.props.managers
         console.log("manager: ", managers)

<label>Manager</label>
            <div className="bootstrap-select-wrapper">
            <select title="Choose" onChange={(event) => this.handleChangeManager(event)}>
            <option value="" title="Choose" data-content="Cancel <span class='reset-label'></span>"></option>
            {managers && managers.length && Object.entries(managers[0]).map(([k, v]) => (
              <option 
                key={k}  
                value={k}  
                name="manager_id" >
                {v.name} {v.surname}
              </option>
            ))}
            </select>

// so there I should create a select about the agenda (for example allowing the user to choose the date)
```

How can I do to create a select about the data, after the manager is choosen?

Comment: Just to be sure, managers[0] is a list of managers? So it is a double nested array?

Comment: yes it's a list of managers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create another Select which will show you the options by populating it based on the selection of manager

Also since the managers is an array, use `managers.map` instead of `Object.entries(manager).map`

```js
handleChangeManager = (e) => {
  const manager_id = e.target.value;
  console.log("manager_id: ", manager_id)
  this.setState({manager_id : manager_id})
}

handleChangeAgenda = (e) => {
  const manager = this.props.managers[0][this.state.manager_id];
  const index = e.target.value
  this.setState({agenda : manager.agendas[index]})
}
render() {
   let managers = this.props.managers
   console.log("manager: ", managers)
   const manager_id = this.state.manager_id;
   const selectedManager = manager_id? mangers[0][manger_id];
   const agendas = (selectedManager || {}).agendas;
   return (
        <label>Manager</label>
        <div className="bootstrap-select-wrapper">
          <select title="Choose" onChange={(event) => this.handleChangeManager(event)}>
          <option value="" title="Choose" data-content="Cancel <span class='reset-label'></span>"></option>
          {managers && managers.length && Object.entries(managers[0]).map(([k, v]) => (
            <option 
              key={k}  
              value={k}  
              name="manager_id" >
              {v.name} {v.surname}
            </option>
          ))}
          </select>
          <select title="Choose Agenda" onChange={(event) => this.handleChangeAgenda(event)}>
          <option value="" title="Choose" data-content="Cancel <span class='reset-label'></span>"></option>
          {agendas && agendas.map((v, index) => (
            <option 
              key={k}  
              value={index}  
              name="manager_id" >
              {v.start_at} - {v.end_at}
            </option>
          ))}
          </select>
        </div>
   )   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, manager is a list of object that inside has an array Agemda

Comment: Yeah I saw the sample and posted a code around that

Comment: Ok I have tried your code, the problem is that in the render `manager_id` is not defined

Comment: Sorry, It should be used from state, this.state.manager_id. I updated the code.

Comment: In the Agenda select: `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. Could be the problem that at the beginning the manager_id is not defined?

Comment: I am sorry, the code wasn't tested. There might be typos and small cases left to fix here and there but the idea is as shown in the code.  `agendas && agendas.map` will fix the current error. However I am pretty sure you would be able to handle things like this on your own too

Comment: You are right, it's better with agendas && agendas.map but why in your opinion, when I choose the manager it prints me a warning: this.agenda is not a function

Comment: Probably because you haven't removed `this.agenda(manager_id)` from your handleChangeManager

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213224/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-jack23).